# convert image to binary on android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, binary

How to convert image to binary and show result on `Text view` ??

I tried this source code but I can't continue, I am newbie.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int codeA, int resl, Intent data){
    if(codeA == HASIL_LOAD_PICT && resl == RESULT_OK && null !=data){
        Uri choosepict = data.getData();
        String[] filepath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cr = getContentResolver().query(choosepict, filepath, null, null, null);
        cr.moveToFirst();

        int colIndex = cr.getColumnIndex(filepath[0]);
        String filepathme = cr.getString(colIndex);
        cr.close();

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepathme));
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just read the stream raw then instead of decoding it?

Answer (score 0):

try the following for image :

```
   bmImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImage2, 0, byteImage2.length));
```